# LogVSAccessor: Warning: Couldn't access Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I am having problems compiling my project. Each time I try I get this:

`LogVSAccessor: Warning: Couldn't access Visual Studio`

I have tried running the game as administrator, I've reinstalled visual studio 17. I have the necessary visual studio addons. I just can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Where do you compile? In UE4, click Compile or in VS, click Build?

Answer (score 1):

1. Close the Unreal Engine.
2. Make sure Visual Studio and Visual Studio Installer are up to date.
3. Open Visual Studio Installer, click in "Modify" and enable:

   - "Desktop development with .NET"
   - "Game development with C++"
4. If necessary, restarts your computer.
5. Go to the **root** folder of your project, right-click in **.uproject** file and **"Generate Visual Studio project files"**.

I hope I can help you. I had the same problem and solved it that way.

Comment: Even after that UE can't feel that VS is launched already - shows LOADING VISUAL STUDIO message

Comment: Hey @Tertium, what your UE4 version? Some people say it was fixed after 4.19.